# JSF prerenderview listener not executed on page forward?

Tags: jsf, event-handling

What I'm going to describe can be the expected behaviour for people who know the JSF phase cycle well, but it is not obvious for me, so I ask for confirmation.
In a JSF page I put a listener for a prerenderview event.
The page is processed in consequence of a jsf-forward. The listener is not executed.
If I access the page directly through its url (perfroming a GET) the listener is executed.
Is there something wrong with my code or is this the right behaviour ?
I searched a lot on internet but didn't find anything useful.

Update
As I stated in the comments I jumped to wrong conclusion. What I described is not a general behaviour but a special case due to bugs or a more complex scenario.

Update 2
After further investigation I came to this conclusion: the problem seems to be related to a wrong way to put the preRenderView listener in a page which uses templates. Unfortunately it works in some circumstances and not in others.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
 <f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{permessitemporaneiController.preCreate}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
...
```

I should have created an insert area inside the template and put the  tag inside a  in the previous code.

The weird thing is that with the 'wrong' code the listener is correctly called with GET requests, but doesn't work with a jsf-forward. Why ??

Thanks
Filippo

Comment: What I was trying to achieve was a method invocation on a backing bean everytime the page is rendered to the user. The Backing bean is sessionScoped so no @PostConstruct option. The Listener seemed a good option but I had to switch to an explicit method call via el #{bean.voidMethod()} on the beginning of the page as ugly as reliable.

Comment: Maybe this wouldn't be the best advice, but you can write a filter that will be executed only for your page (or a group of pages, that's your decision) and the filter could execute your bean method before calling `chain.doFilter(request, response);`.

Comment: What JSF impl/version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mojarra 2.0. I have to say that I jumped to wrong conclusions. In fact I wrote a two page application where prerenderview listener is correctly called during page forward. The problem with the initial web application needs more investigation and unfortunately I have no clue to follow. The code for setting the listener is so simple I cannot understand where it can be wrong.

Comment: @BalusC Any idea of the weird behaviour described at the end of Update 2 ? I have always thought the code posted before was correct because it worked... until I used it with Get requests...